# count number of positive consecutive positive and negative

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm really stuck. I have a dataframe with a column that goes like the following

```
Dailychange:
1
2
3
0
-1
-2
-3
1
2
```

I want to calculate number of positive and negative consecutively into two lists with the output pos[3,2] nutral[1] neg[3]. I have tried resolving it with a simple loop like

```
    # for i in symbol:
    #     if (symbol['Dailychange']>0):
    #         counter+=1
    #         cons_list.append(counter)
    #     else:
    #         counter=0
    #         cons_list.append(counter)
    # print(cons_list)
```

and this outputs an error, due to my if statement. Then I tried to use the where function

```
symbol['positive']=symbol.where(symbol['Dailychange']>0,'positive','Negative')
```

That didn't work out either. I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802800/pandas-dataframe-how-to-groupby-consecutive-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need a new para here , I created by using `np.where`

```
df['New']=np.where(df['Num']>0,'positive',np.where(df['Num']==0,'Nutral','Negative'))
s=df.groupby([df['New'],(df['New']!=df['New'].shift()).cumsum()]).size().reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
s
Out[41]: 
New
Negative    3
Nutral      1
positive    3
positive    2
dtype: int64
```

More info

```
(df['New']!=df['New'].shift()).cumsum()
Out[804]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    3
7    4
8    4
Name: New, dtype: int32

(df['New']!=df['New'].shift())
Out[805]: 
0     True 
1    False
2    False
3     True # here is the status change 
4     True # here is the status change 
5    False  # those one do not change should carry over the same number as before 
6    False
7     True # here is the status change 
8    False
Name: New, dtype: bool
```

We consider the consecutively positive or negative as one group, once they changed they blone to next group

Also one more thing True + False =1

Comment: Hi really appreciate your answer. I get the first line, the key is using numpy instead of pandas. But I'm confuse about the syntax of the second line. How is cumsum come into play. Thanks again.

Comment: @Longroadahead (df['New']!=df['New'].shift()).cumsum() , this is to find the consecutively: -), think about number 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1, find the group of repeat pattern will be 000111222333

Comment: I just can't wrap my head around it for some reason, my understanding is this. igroup by df['New'] and the condition is (df['New'] not equal to the next inline of cumulative sum) then .size find the number of element and reset_index is putting them together. I just don't get the cumulative sum part. Really appreciate your help on this!!

Comment: @Longroadahead add more info

Comment: Isn't cumulative sum adds value after another? ie: 1+1+1 etc. I must misunderstood the doc somehow.

Comment: @Longroadahead yess it will , for example , T F T F , cumsum will be 1122, they only add up the True value with means if it is False It will carry over the previous value ( They are in the same group)

Answer (score 0):

pd.cut and groupby is exactly what you are looking for -

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 0, -1, -2, -3, 1, 2],columns=['Dailychange'])
col = x['Dailychange']
x['Labels'] = list(pd.cut(x['Dailychange'],[-float("inf"),-0.1,0.1,float("inf")],labels=['neg','neutral','pos']))
# for i,e in enumerate(x['Labels']):
#     print(col[i],x['Labels'][i])
x['chunk_number'] = (x['Labels'] != x['Labels'].shift()).cumsum()
grouped_df = x.groupby('chunk_number')
for i in grouped_df.groups.keys():
    print(list(grouped_df.get_group(i)['Dailychange']))
```

Also Checkout: [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) | [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416684/python-pandas-cut) | [Another Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835793/pandas-group-by-consecutive-ranges)